# rendering action twice in a page. event is hit twice where it should be only once

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a admin.cshtml file with below code.

```
@Html.Partial("_IdentificationForToday", Model)
....
....

 @{
    Html.RenderAction("Index", "NavigationTree");
  }
```

in _IdentificationForToday.cshtml has.

```
<div class="span2">
        @{
            Html.RenderAction("Index", "NavigationTree");
        }
    </div>
```

when i am clicking on navigation tree below code is getting hit twice.

```
var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
            if (children.is(':visible')) {
                children.hide('fast');
                $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
            }
            else {
                children.show('fast');
                $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Did you look carefully at your code? You are calling `RenderAction()` of the `NavigationTree` in two files, so it'll render two times.

Comment: yes i need them twice but event should not be called twice is their a way to stop it.